# How to make fmt.Sprint spring work for parameters in a URL?

Tags: go

I have a reverse-proxy that returns body responses from a 3rd party API. This 3rd party API uses pagination, so my reverse-proxy path requires parameters for page number.

I'm having trouble using `fmt.Sprint` to pass the parameter from the reverse-proxy URL to 3rd Party API request.

```
func (s *Server) getReverseProxy(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["page"]

    if !ok || len(keys[0]) < 1 {
        log.Println("Url Param 'page' is missing")
        return
    }

    // Query()["key"] will return an array of items,
    // we only want the single item.
    key := keys[0]

    log.Println("Url Param 'page' is: " + string(key))

    // create http client to make GET request to reverse-proxy
    client := &http.Client{}

    // create 3rd party request

    // creating this request is causing me the issue due to the page parameter 
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprint("https://url.com/path?&page%5Bsize%5D=100&page%5Bnumber%5D=%s\n", key), nil)

    // more stuff down here but omitted for brevity.
}
```

Looking at the `http.NewRequest` 3rd party api request, the `%s\n` part would be where they `key` is passed for the `page parameter`.

How can I correctly pass this variable to the url? In python what I'm looking to use is an f-string. Not sure im doing that correctly for Go.

EDIT:
New implementation using url.Vaues()

```
func (s *Server) getReverseProxy(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    keys, ok := r.URL.Query()["page"]

    if !ok || len(keys[0]) < 1 {
        log.Println("Url Param 'page' is missing")
        return
    }

    // Query()["key"] will return an array of items,
    // we only want the single item.
    key := keys[0]

    log.Println("Url Param 'page' is: " + string(key))
    params := url.Values{
        "page[size]":        []string{"100"},
        "page[" + key + "]": []string{"1"},
    }
    u := &url.URL{
        Scheme:   "https",
        Host:     "url.com",
        Path:     "/path",
        RawQuery: params.Encode(),
    }

    // create http client to make GET request
    client := &http.Client{}

    // create a variable for the JSON model expected from Terraform Cloud API
    var data models.TerraformResponse
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", u.String(), nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably be constructing the URL and query using the `net/url` package. This has the advantage that it is much safer.

```golang
params := url.Values{
    "page[size]":        []string{"100"},
    "page[" + key + "]": []string{"1"},
}
u := &url.URL{
    Scheme:   "https",
    Host:     "url.com",
    Path:     "/path",
    RawQuery: params.Encode(),
}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", u.String(), nil)
```

Trying to use `fmt.Sprintf()` to construct URLs is a bit more likely to backfire.

If you want to construct a URL with `fmt.Sprintf`, you’ll need to escape all the `%` in the format string, and escape special characters in the arguments.

```golang
fmt.Sprint("https://url.com/path?&page%%5Bsize%%5D=100&page%%5B%s%%5D=1",
    url.QueryEscape(key))
```

The `url.QueryEscape()` function escapes the characters in a string so it can be safely placed in a URL query. It’s not necessary if you construct the URL with `url.Values` and `url.URL`.

Comment: This option looks way better, thanks for presenting it. I am having trouble trying to replicate it however, please see how I implemented above. Would appreciate if you see anything wrong. Not able to get the params to work correctly?

Comment: I also made a typo in my original code, in my first attempt I was trying to hit this path: `https://url.com/path?&page%5Bsize%5D=100&page%5Bnumber%5D=%s\n`. With they key page the value of page[number]. I edited my original code to reflect this.

Comment: you need to set the URL for your incoming request from the url of the request you received.  Then add the stuff you want to add